# Вывод границ городов и штатов США на карте через leaflet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leafletjs

Есть проект на `Angular`, в котором используется директива от `leaflet`. Появилась задача обводить город или штат выбранный пользователем (вроде банально, а решения не нахожу). Нашёл `geoJSON` для штатов, внедрить его не проблема, но для городов такое решение не подойдёт - их же тысячи.

Может есть какой-то сервис, который можно использовать как `overlay` или `layer` для `leaflet`, в который можно передать что-то типа `type=city&name=New+York` и он обведёт именно `New York`?